# Error's With Signup & Login PHP with Hostinger

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin, forum

So I have been Building A Forum With A Friend & He Has Challenged Me To Do A Lot Of The Server Side Stuff As He Tries Designing & I receive a lot of these error's

DISCLAIMER: I KNOW ALOT OF THIS HAS BEEN POSTED BUT I FIND IT HARD TO UNDERSTAND FOR ME.

DISCLAIMER: I AM INTERMEDIATE SO I AM NOT EXPERT AT PHP AND HAVE DEBUGGED FOR HOURS ON THIS.

Here is my login.php

```
<?php
//This page let log in
include('config.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    unset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['userid']);
    setcookie('username', '', time()-100);
    setcookie('password', '', time()-100);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="<?php echo $design; ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $design; ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Forum" /></a>
        </div>
<div class="message">You have successfully been logged out.<br />
<a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>">Home</a></div>
<?php
}
else
{
    $ousername = '';
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
    {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $ousername = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username']));
            $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
        }
        else
        {
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $password = $_POST['password'];
        }
        $req = mysql_query('select password,id from users where username="'.$username.'"');
        $dn = mysql_fetch_array($req);
        if($dn['password']==sha1($password) and mysql_num_rows($req)>0)
        {
            $form = false;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];
            if(isset($_POST['memorize']) and $_POST['memorize']=='yes')
            {
                $one_year = time()+(60*60*24*365);
                setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], $one_year);
                setcookie('password', sha1($password), $one_year);
            }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="<?php echo $design; ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $design; ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Forum" /></a>
        </div>
<div class="message">You have successfully been logged.<br />
<a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>">Home Page</a></div>
<?php
        }
        else
        {
            $form = true;
            $message = 'The username or password you entered are not good.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $form = true;
    }
    if($form)
    {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="<?php echo $design; ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $design; ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Forum" /></a>
        </div>
<?php
if(isset($message))
{
    echo '<div class="message">'.$message.'</div>';
}
?>
<div class="content">
<?php
$nb_new_pm = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(*) as nb_new_pm from pm where ((user1="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user1read="no") or (user2="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user2read="no")) and id2="1"'));
$nb_new_pm = $nb_new_pm['nb_new_pm'];
?>
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_left">
        <a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>">Forum Index</a> &gt; Login
    </div>
    <div class="box_right">
        <a href="list_pm.php">Your messages(<?php echo $nb_new_pm; ?>)</a> - <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a> (<a href="login.php">Logout</a>)
    </div>
    <div class="clean"></div>
</div>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        Please, type your IDs to log:<br />
        <div class="login">
            <label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo htmlentities($ousername, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" /><br />
            <label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
            <label for="memorize">Remember</label><input type="checkbox" name="memorize" id="memorize" value="yes" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
        <div class="foot"><a href="http://www.anmolb.esy.es">Developers Site</a> - Developed By LivingLife_</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are the error's I receive with the login page.

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/config.php on line 9

Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/config.php on line 9

Deprecated: mysql_select_db(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/config.php on line 10

Warning: mysql_select_db(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/config.php on line 10

Warning: mysql_select_db(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/config.php on line 10

Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/login.php on line 38

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/login.php on line 38

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/login.php on line 38

Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/login.php on line 41

Warning: mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/login.php on line 41

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/login.php on line 41

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/login.php on line 42
Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/login.php on line 102

Warning: mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/login.php on line 102

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/login.php on line 102

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/login.php on line 102
```

Here is the signup.php code

```
<?php
//This page let users sign up
include('config.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="<?php echo $design; ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
        <title>Sign Up</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $design; ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Espace Membre" /></a>
        </div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['passverif'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['avatar']) and $_POST['username']!='')
{
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['passverif'] = stripslashes($_POST['passverif']);
        $_POST['email'] = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
        $_POST['avatar'] = stripslashes($_POST['avatar']);
    }
    if($_POST['password']==$_POST['passverif'])
    {
        if(strlen($_POST['password'])>=6)
        {
            if(preg_match('#^(([a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+\.?)*[a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)@(([a-z0-9-_]+\.?)*[a-z0-9-_]+)\.[a-z]{2,}$#i',$_POST['email']))
            {
                $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
                $password = mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($_POST['password']));
                $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
                $avatar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['avatar']);
                $dn = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('select id from users where username="'.$username.'"'));
                if($dn==0)
                {
                    $dn2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('select id from users'));
                    $id = $dn2+1;
                    if(mysql_query('insert into users(id, username, password, email, avatar, signup_date) values ('.$id.', "'.$username.'", "'.$password.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$avatar.'", "'.time().'")'))
                    {
                        $form = false;
?>
<div class="message">You have successfully been signed up. You can now log in.<br />
<a href="login.php">Log in</a></div>
<?php
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $form = true;
                        $message = 'An error occurred while signing you up.';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $form = true;
                    $message = 'Another user already use this username.';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $form = true;
                $message = 'The email you typed is not valid.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $form = true;
            $message = 'Your password must have a minimum of 6 characters.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $form = true;
        $message = 'The passwords you entered are not identical.';
    }
}
else
{
    $form = true;
}
if($form)
{
    if(isset($message))
    {
        echo '<div class="message">'.$message.'</div>';
    }
?>
<div class="content">
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_left">
        <a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>">Forum Index</a> &gt; Sign Up
    </div>
    <div class="box_right">
        <a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a> - <a href="login.php">Login</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clean"></div>
</div>
    <form action="signup.php" method="post">
        Please fill this form to sign up:<br />
        <div class="center">
            <label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?>" /><br />
            <label for="password">Password<span class="small">(6 characters min.)</span></label><input type="password" name="password" /><br />
            <label for="passverif">Password<span class="small">(verification)</span></label><input type="password" name="passverif" /><br />
            <label for="email">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?>" /><br />
            <label for="avatar">Avatar<span class="small">(optional)</span></label><input type="text" name="avatar" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['avatar'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['avatar'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?>" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
        <div class="foot"><a href="http://www.anmolb.esy.es">Developers Site</a> - Developed By LivingLife_</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are the error that i have with this code

```
    Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/config.php on line 9

        Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/config.php on line 9

        Deprecated: mysql_select_db(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/config.php on line 10

        Warning: mysql_select_db(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/config.php on line 10

        Warning: mysql_select_db(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/config.php on line 10
Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 33

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 33

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 33

Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 34

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 34

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 34

Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 35

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 35

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 35

Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 36

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 36

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 36

Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 37

Warning: mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 37

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 37

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 37

Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 40

Warning: mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 40

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 40

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 40

Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 42

Warning: mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 42

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u134164949/public_html/forum/signup.php on line 42
```

Thank you for any other information, This is kinda a first experience for me :)

Comment: `mysql* function` is deprecated and it'll give you errors on PHP newer versions... I suggest you use `mysqli` instead

Comment: How can i fix that is the question that I have as I really don't do server side stuff that much as I have said the farthest I have gone into php is making a responsive form that emails you stuff.

Comment: Please [don't use `mysql_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead. As for all those errors, if you had read them, they're actually quite helpful in this instance.

Comment: Ahh I see what you are saying and would that effect all the code and would I put it on the login.php file. or my functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting `mysqli_connect`... replace all instances of `mysql` to `mysqli`.. you're using procedural approach... and `mysqli` offers that approach....

`mysqli` is the improve version of `mysql`.. don't use `mysql` anymore.

Comment: I will try this. Shall I do this for all files?

Comment: be careful, mysqli doesn't has the same api of mysql, even with the function procedural style.

Comment: @Coder101 better you read this... http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp